# Changing CMD window properties programmatically

Tags: windows, cmd

How can I change the appearance of my current CMD window?
I know there is a 'mode' and 'color' commands that give you some control, but it's not enough...

Is it possible to change Screen Buffer Size separately? To turn QuickEdit mode on/off?
Is there an API for this?

Answer (score 6):

Search engines are amazing things :).

Search for [Windows Console API](http://www.bing.com/search?q=windows+console+api&src=IE-SearchBox&FORM=IE8SRC) and the 2nd link is: [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682087(VS.85).aspx).  Digging in a tiny bit more and you find the interestingly named "[SetConsoleMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686033(VS.85).aspx)" and "[SetConsoleScreenBufferSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686044(VS.85).aspx)" APIs which appear to set the console mode (which includes quick edit mode) and screen buffer size.

I've not used the APIs so I don't know if there are any caveats, but from the documentation, these seem to be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

another way: use reg /? to query your registry for `reg query HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console`. There you can see keys like ScreenBufferSize etc. Use reg to delete the key and add it back with new values. Type reg /? on the command line to see its help usage. make sure you backup registry before trying.